# Django: Order objects based on likes for popular feed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to implement 'Popular' Feed. I want to show the series of posts which has the likes the most.

Here is abstract model schema.

```
(Model) Like 
      user = User
      content_type = Post, User, Group
      object_id = 22

(Model) Post
      user = User
      content = ''
      created_at = '12082017'
```

In views.py, I want to get sorted queryset like,

```
 Post.objects.order_by('-like')[:30]
```

Since my Post model doesn't have like field, I can't use `order_by`.

I'm thinking about adding `score` field to track of likes and current time since then. Do you think it will work? :)

Also any thought or advice on how to make popular feed will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something called the reverse generic relation for this purpose:

[Reverse Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations)

Add the reverse generic relation to your post model and you can get the count of the number of likes and then order it based on likes for popularity based ordering.

In your post model add:

```
likes = GenericRelation(Like)
```

Maybe use annotate for ordering:

```
Post.objects.annotate(like_count=Count('likes')).order_by('-like_count')
```

You would get an additional field '**like_count**' for each post object plus it will be ordered based on the number of likes.

Comment: THIS WORKS! :) Thank you so much. Great

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005427/calling-another-serializer-from-the-serializer-messes-up-uri