# Calling another serializer from the Serializer messes up URI

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-settings

I'm in the debugging mode and I want to set default ImageField to return full URL`localhost:8000/path`.

Here is current JSON data

```
 ...
 "img": "http://localhost:8000/media/outfits/1/4.png",
    "tagged_clothes": [
        {
            "cloth_image": "/media/clothes/1/7.png", <- This happens when I use settings.py debugging file
            "id": 6,
            "b_clothtype": "ETC",
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' # if I change this variable as 'localhost:8000/media/',
                      # JSON returns correct URLs but I couldn't see the image.
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media_cdn')
```

Here is working example with AWS settings. It shows `http://localhost:8000/media/blahblah` correctly.

```
    # HERE is working example in AWS. It returns full URI
# AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "aws key" #S3
# AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "secret key" #S3
# AWS_FILE_EXPIRE = 200 #S3
# AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True #S3
# AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True #S3
# DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'asd' #S3
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'asd' #S3
# AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'asd' #S3
# S3DIRECT_REGION = 'us-west-2' #S3

# S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME #S3
# MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME #S3
# MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL #S3

# STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/' #S3
# import datetime #S3
# two_months = datetime.timedelta(days=61) # S3
# date_two_months_later = datetime.date.today() + two_months #S3
# expires = date_two_months_later.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y 20:00:00 GMT") #S3
# AWS_HEADERS = { #S3
#   'Expires': expires,
#   'Cache-Control': 'max-age=%d' % (int(two_months.total_seconds()), ),
# }
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

### CODE

This happens **only if I call another** `Serializer` in the serializer

```
def get_tagged_clothes(self, obj):
        clothes = obj.clothes_set;
        if obj.user != self.context['request'].user:
            clothes = clothes.filter(only_me=False)
        return CListSerializer(clothes, many=True).data <- Sending wrong URI.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use request's [`build_absolute_uri`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) method:

```
class ClothesListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cloth_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Cloth
        fields = ('cloth_image' ...)


    def get_cloth_image(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        photo_url = obj.cloth_image.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(photo_url)
```

Note that you may need to add request to serializer's context inside your view for this:

```
serializer = ClothesListSerializer(Cloth, context={'request': request})
```

But if you are using generic class based view this will do automatically.

Comment: It makes right image absoluate url when I use AWS. I have to separate deploy and test methods for `build_absolute_uri` and it's inefficient. Sorry

Comment: @JohnBaek not sure if this helps but you can check DEBUG settings value inside `get_cloth_image`: `from django.conf import settings` and `if settings.DEBUG:`.

Comment: I just edited the question. Does this help you solve the problem?

Comment: Just changed question name, too. I hope this helps

Comment: @JohnBaek can you post source code of both serializers? Just guess try to add context to the second serializer: `return CListSerializer(clothes, many=True, context=self.context).data`

Comment: WOW this works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Could you explain why this is working? this is awesome. great job

Comment: @JohnBaek when serializer try to build url it required `request` object. As I said in my answer Class based view pass this object to the serializer automatically with `context` dict. But when you call second serializer you didn't provide this dict. So serializer was not able to build url.Hope it is little bit clearer now:)

Comment: And this problem happens when I refer to ManyToMany objects. `obj.outfits.first().outfit_img:
                print(obj.outfits.first().outfit_img.url)
                return obj.outfits.first().outfit_img.url`

Comment: Just calling `obj.outfits.first().outfit_img.url` everytime return only `MEDIA_URL` + filename value. To make full url you need to use `request.build_absolute_uri` with this value yourself: `request.build_absolute_uri(obj.outfits.first().outfit_img.url)`.